# passing multiple callback in a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
funcOne(cb) {
  //some async actions
  cb(resp) //pass resp to callback function
}



fucntionTwo(resp) { console.log(resp) }
fucntionThree(resp) { console.log(resp) }

funcOne(funcTwo)
funcOne(funcThree)
```

function one will run twice with above case, **how can I make funcOne run once but trigger funcTwo and funcThree?** I need to pass the resp from funcOne and execute `funcTwo` and `funcThree` Means passing multiple callback in funcOne.

I know I can pass multiple args but is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) syntax and then use a `forEach` and `apply` the functions. Something like

```js
function funcOne(...cb) {
        console.log("one");
        cb.forEach(s => s.apply());
}

function funcTwo() {
        console.log("two");
}

function funcThree() {
        console.log("three");
}

funcOne(funcTwo, funcThree);
```

and you can call `funcOne` with any number of function parameters.

Comment: can I pass param to cb like `cb.forEach(s => s.apply('param from funcOne'));`?

Answer (score 2):

Simply pass multiple arguments as callback functions

```
function funcOne(cb1, cb2) {
  cb1();
  cb2();
}
```

if number of callbacks are going to be dynamic then iterate `arguments`

```
function funcOne() {
  Array.from( arguments ).forEach( s => typeof s == "function" && s() );
}
```

and invoke it as

```
funcOne( function(){ console.log(1) }, function(){ console.log(2) }, function(){ console.log(3) } )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the two callback into your functionOne:

```
funcOne(cb1, cb2) {
    cb1();
    cb2();
}

funcOne(funcTwo, funcThree);
```

Comment: I got this but is this the only way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It's so easy:

```
function One(arg) {
    Two(arg);
    Three(arg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass two functions as arguments

```
funcOne(a, b) {
  a(); b();
}

funcOne(funcTwo, funcThree)
```

If the scope of the functions is the way you have mentioned then you do not need to even pass them as arguments. Just directly call them.

```js
function funcOne() {
  //some async actions
  var resp = "Some response";
  fucntionTwo(resp);
  fucntionTwo(resp);
}

funcOne();

function fucntionTwo(resp) { console.log(resp) }
function fucntionThree(resp) { console.log(resp) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of arguments keyword.

Demo Example

```
function test()
{ for(var i=0; i< arguments.length; i++)
   arguments[i]();
}

test(fun1 , fun2)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can follow this code, I hope your problem will be solved**

```
function funcOne(fucntionTwo, fucntionThree) {

    fucntionTwo(resp)
    fucntionThree(resp)
}

funcOne(function (resp) {
    console.log(resp)
}, function (resp) {
        console.log(resp)
})
```